# arrange items in flex column without providing the height to parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Hi I have this scenreo like this, I have achieved this till upto a certain limit but for that, I need to give the Height to UL,

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 120px;
}

li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

which I dont want because if my ul will have 13 items and in that Condition, I need them to arrenge like this.

[image: like this]

Order of items doesn't matter for me, but the requirement is that a single row will not have more than 5 items,

and if it has 6 items in total then 3 above and 3 beneath needed. So items will be divided equally in rows like this. and this condition has already been achieved.

[image]

I am open to using the grid as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would serve the purpose but it's all i can come up with.

Requires scaffolding and some funky calculations to care for the margins and keeping all items the same size.

If you want to remove the margins don't forget to adjust the calculation

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


li {
  list-style: none;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 0 40%;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 0 60%;
}

.parent>li>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent>li>ul>li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.left>ul>li {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
}

.right>ul>li {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.3% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="left">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="right">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**
Now i don't understand how's the amount of items changes so everything here is just go you and idea of how this might be achieved

This approach uses grid which is not by any means bad, the problem is that the item before last will have to span across the width.

Now this will only serve the purpose when we have 13 items, so you'll have to disable it when there isn't

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  margin: 30px;
}

li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

/* select before last item to push last item down */
ul>li:nth-last-child(2) {
  background: lime;
  grid-column: 2 /6;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is only one UL element and all the items in there are LI coming from a loop, so I can not use this structure. Structure will remain same given by me,

Answer (score 0):

in order to remove height from `ul` element, remove the height and on `li` the following:

```
.ul {
height: 100px;
width: 250px;
background: red;
margin-bottom: 10px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

ideally you should user max-width and min-width on the `li` element.

By using this you would run into a problem of alignment of the vertical `li` elements.
to resolve that problem, use empty li elements to match the count of the last row to the above rows and set the empty `li` `min-width` to 0;

That should be able to solve your issue.
Hope that helps!!!!

Comment: hi divneet, Thanks for the suggestion, but I can not do that, All the items (li) are coming from a loop which I can not change or control. So structure will be the same which I provide, I can not put empty LI in there, I hope its more clear now